# Работа функции sys.argv

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я только недавно начал изучать Python, разбираюсь с библиотекой pyaudio. В коде, который воспроизводит wav файл впервые для меня встретилась функция `sys.argv` из библиотеки `sys`. Если `sys.argv[0]` путь к скрипту и его название. Но непонятно откуда берёт свое значение `sys.argv[1]` в коде, представленном ниже.

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

CHUNK = 1024

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Plays a wave file.\n\nUsage: %s filename.wav" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(-1)

wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)

data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

while data != '':
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Comment: В коде ниже, значение, переданное программе в качестве первого аргумента, попадет в sys.argv[1], т.е. будет открыт файл с именем, указанным в первом параметре при вызове программы. Например: python myscript.py /tmp/myfile.wav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде ниже, значение, переданное программе в качестве первого аргумента, попадет в

> sys.argv[1]

, т.е. будет открыт файл с именем, указанным в первом параметре при вызове программы. Например:

```
python myscript.py /tmp/myfile.wav
```