# Получение пути файла перетаскиванием этого файла на скомпилированный exe

Tags: python, tkinter, drag-n-drop, path

Мне нужно реализовать импорт полного пути файла в переменную перетаскиванием этого файла на скомпилированный exe файл. Я в программировании новичок поэтому я нашел информацию что это можно сделать с помощью tkinter но так и не смог понять как сделать

Ожидаемый результат после перетаскивания:

```
file = 'C:\file\path\file.exp'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14267900/5741205

Comment: @MaxUMy Я находил эту тему но не смог понять её

Comment: tkinter Вам актуален только если вы делаете графический интерфейс иначе смысла мало. В ответах прекрасный вариант предложили )

Answer (score 2):

Я нашел решение задачи

```
import sys

path = sys.argv[1]
```

[Работа функции sys.argv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593621/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-sys-argv)

Comment: а как же "drag and drop"?? ;)

Comment: @MaxU если имелось в виду просто перетаскивание файла на экзешник, то это так и будет работать. Если нужно открытие при перетскивании в окно, то все "немного" сложнее.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, не знал!

Comment: так это и есть то что мне нужно, я просто не всегда точно могу выразить мысль так как я новичок